# Django Rest Frame Performance of nested model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I profiled my Django App using [silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) and it turns out that for 200000 db-entries a GET list call takes 701ms in total of which only 36ms are spent on queries (I use `prefetch_related` and `select_related` and Pagination)

Since I assumed the db-queries would take the most time, I am wondering whether I am doing something wrong since 95% of the time is not spent on queries.

My main measurement model is very nested and looks like this

```py
class Measurement(models.Model):
    filetype = models.ForeignKey(Filetype)
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    sensorpositions = models.ManyToManyField('Sensorposition')
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name = "measurementexperiment")
    data = models.FileField(null=True)
```

and the Frontend expects a detailed nested-json output for every field, so the Serializer does not only return the pk but also all the subfields of the Foreign-models:

```py
class MeasurementSerializer(MeasurementSerializer):
    sensor = SensorDetailSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    sensorpositions = SensorpositionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    experiment = ExperimentDetailForMeasurementSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    filetype = FiletypeSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

class ExperimentDetailForMeasurementSerializer(ExperimentSerializer):
    persons = PersonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    layout = LayoutSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
```

So am I simply loosing a lot of time because of the nested serialization or are response times like 701ms normal?

Comment: Looks more that serializing 200k items will require a lot of CPU time. Python is not very effective with large numbers. Usually for ~1M, is starts taking seconds. Perhaps you should make the page size smaller.

Comment: But doesn't a pagination with size 100 only serialize 100 objects at a time per page?

Comment: well the question is how many *related* objects you retrieve and thus put in the response. For all these related objects, serialization is necessary as well.

Comment: with related objects you mean all ForeignKeys or only those with `related_name=... `?